# Is a language with an extension a valid golfing language?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

In a current challenge, [Falsify brief truths](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80822/falsify-brief-truths/), `@Lynn` proposed an edit to my Haskell answer that requires the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language extension.

As this extension is not part of the `Haskell2010` language, it seems to me that one might consider `Haskell2010 + NoMonomorphismRestriction` to be its own language.

#### Pros

- Language extensions could encourage creative solutions.
- Extensions don't usually save more than a couple bytes, as far as I know.
- Activating language extensions take more bytes than they're worth, currently. (`-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` is 27 bytes, while the proposed solution is 37 bytes).
- Some people (including myself) enjoy learning programming techniques from code golf, that can be applied to non-golf coding. This would open up more opportunities for that.
- Problems like: "Yes, for this challenge I'm using extension number `689865434678` to Pyth, which makes the blank program the solution to this challenge" are covered by the [MetaGolf loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076/48962) and the [Using a made-up language loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1071/48962).

#### Cons

- I'm not sure what precisely constitutes a language extension

What do you think?

Comment: So then any [`-M` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) would be free for Perl? That'd be... amazing.

Comment: @msh210 There is a huge difference between language extensions and modules. Modules contain actual code and give you additional functions for free, while extensions modify how the language behave and what is or isn't allowed. For example, I'd say that "use strict" should be free, but "use Acme::Foo" should not.

Answer (score 19):

Using a third-party library/module/extension/whatever has always been allowed by default. It should be noted in the answer that it is not the "vanilla" language (something like `Language + Library/Libraries` is the most common way). However, any code needed to access the functionality of the library (such as Python's `import`, C/C++'s `#include` and `-l`, Perl's `use` or `-M`, Node.js's `require`, etc.) must be included in the submission code. For example, if you're using `Python + NumPy`, you don't get `import numpy as np` for free. What you *do* get for free is the assumption that a certain third-party library (or set of third-party libraries) is present on the machine, and can be used via the normal mechanisms of the language.

On a related note, you can also mix languages this way, such as through pipes in Bash-like shells.

Comment: What if you're writing a browser-JS solution with, for example, jQuery? There is no require or equivalent for the browser

Comment: @Upgoat I'd consider jQuery its own separate language for these purposes, so you get the loading for free (since it would normally be done on the HTML side with a script tag).

Comment: I'm not sure how your answer applies to the specific case I mentioned. The `NoMonorphismRestriction` extension to Haskell only affects the type checker, so it's not adding functions or anything, but you do need a flag, pragma, or `.cabal` setting to activate it (for GHC).

Comment: @MichaelKlein In that case, you'd need to include the flag, pragma, or config setting in your byte count, as per usual.

Comment: @Mego But then it can never be used. I can't imagine that it would ever be worth 27 bytes so an entire class of valid and interesting answers become impossible. Maybe I could upload a script that runs GHC with this flag and call it a new language, but that seems ridiculous. Unless you're advocating a "slippery slope" approach, this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MichaelKlein There's no rule saying you can't make a new "language" that is just Haskell with that option enabled.

Comment: @Mego I know, it just seems ridiculous that doing that would be the solution. Extensions like this don't add any functions or hide bytes, they usually make it more challenging to write code.

Comment: What about, for example, [vim-plugins?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/82427/generate-command-for-fox-9000-chatbot-to-return-arbitrary-amounts-of-gibberish/82446#82446) This doesn't require any code (in the vim program) to include other than having the files present on the machine and in the right folders. Does this mean that any vim-plugin that was published before the challenge is fair-game and doesn't add to the byte count?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan I'd say yes, so long as you included the plugin(s) in the header. It would be different than a vanilla vim submission.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that using a language extension that **only modifies the syntax and/or semantics of the language** should be free and count as a separate language, as long as it **doesn't give you new functions** you can call.

I believe that all Haskell extensions would fall under this category (correct me if I'm wrong), as well as `use strict` and friends in perl, and most flags for the C/C++ compiler. In the case of vim, I think introducing a new normal mode command should count as a function and not a language extension.

There are probably many problematic edge cases I'm missing, but the basic idea is that an extension doesn't give you functionality for free, but changes how code looks and how the language behaves.